# Python load data from text files into sqlite database and passing table name & columns as a parameter

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a huge number of text files, data in each file differs from one file to another.

I would like to loop into the list of files and create sqlite database which includes one table corresponding to each file.

Data is provided in the text file in the format of "column name":"value"|"column name":"value"| ....etc.

Here are the challenges faced:

- Managed to pass the table name as parameter in the CREATE table SQL query
- How to pass the columns as a variable taking into consideration that the data differs from one file to another? I cannot explicitly define column names as in "INSERT INTO TBL_NAME VALUES (Id INTEGER, Parameter TEXT)" ...etc

Example for the text files:

```
WBTS.txt:
WBTS|version:xxxxxxx|DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxx|Id:2011659|name:VT_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0|BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2|BTSSupportForHSPACM:2|BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0|BroadcastSIB15:0|BroadcastSIB15_2:0|BroadcastSIB15_3:0|DCNLinkStatus:0|DCNSecurityStatus:255|DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0|DSCPHigh:46|DSCPLow:0|DSCPMedDCH:34|DSCPMedHSPA:26|DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3|DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1|DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5|DelayThresholdMax:10000|DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000|DelayThresholdMid:7000|DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000|DelayThresholdMin:5000|DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000|EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0|FreqChangeCapability:2|HARQRVConfiguration:1|HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1|HSDPACCEnabled:1|HSDPAULCToDSCP:34|HSUPACCEnabled:1|HSUPADLCToDSCP:34|HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60|IPBasedRouteIdIub:254|IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0|IPNBId:104|InactCACThresholdATM:170|InactCACThresholdIP:80|InactUsersCIDThreshold:6|IntelligentSDPrioHO:0|IubTransportSharing:0|LoadControlPeriodPS:20|MDCBufferingTime:50|MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460|MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428|MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0|MeasFiltCoeff:5|MinUDPPortIub:1026|NEType:24|NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0|OverbookingSwitch:0|PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2|PSAveragingWindowSize:4|PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0|PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0|PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0|PWSMInUse:0|PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22|PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0|PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6|PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0|PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22|PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0|PWSMShutdownEndHour:6|PWSMShutdownEndMin:0|PWSMWeekday:0|ProbabilityFactorMax:1000|ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000|PrxAlpha:0|PrxMeasAveWindow:20|PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5|PtxAlpha:0|PtxDPCHmax:-30|PtxDPCHmin:-28|PtxMeasAveWindow:10|RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1|RFSharingState:0|RRIndPeriod:40|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1|SBTSId:xxxxx|SatelliteIubUsage:0|SchedulingPeriod:100|TQMId:0|TQMId2:0|TQMId3:0|TQMId4:0|ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0|WBTSChangeOrigin:2|WBTSName:VT_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|WBTSSWBuildId:No information available|WinACRABsetupDL:5|WinACRABsetupUL:5|WinLCHSDPA:5|WinLCHSUPA:5|
WBTS|version:xxxxxxx|DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxx|Id:2110802|name:ET_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0|BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2|BTSSupportForHSPACM:2|BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0|BroadcastSIB15:0|BroadcastSIB15_2:0|BroadcastSIB15_3:0|DCNLinkStatus:0|DCNSecurityStatus:255|DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0|DSCPHigh:46|DSCPLow:0|DSCPMedDCH:34|DSCPMedHSPA:26|DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3|DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1|DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5|DelayThresholdMax:10000|DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000|DelayThresholdMid:7000|DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000|DelayThresholdMin:5000|DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000|EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0|FreqChangeCapability:2|HARQRVConfiguration:1|HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1|HSDPACCEnabled:1|HSDPAULCToDSCP:34|HSUPACCEnabled:1|HSUPADLCToDSCP:34|HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60|IPBasedRouteIdIub:272|IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0|IPNBId:110|InactCACThresholdATM:170|InactCACThresholdIP:80|InactUsersCIDThreshold:6|IntelligentSDPrioHO:0|IubTransportSharing:0|LoadControlPeriodPS:20|MDCBufferingTime:50|MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460|MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428|MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0|MeasFiltCoeff:5|MinUDPPortIub:1026|NEType:24|NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0|OverbookingSwitch:0|PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2|PSAveragingWindowSize:4|PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0|PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0|PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0|PWSMInUse:0|PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22|PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0|PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6|PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0|PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22|PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0|PWSMShutdownEndHour:6|PWSMShutdownEndMin:0|PWSMWeekday:0|ProbabilityFactorMax:1000|ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000|PrxAlpha:0|PrxMeasAveWindow:20|PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5|PtxAlpha:0|PtxDPCHmax:-30|PtxDPCHmin:-28|PtxMeasAveWindow:10|RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1|RFSharingState:0|RRIndPeriod:40|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1|SBTSId:xxxxx|SatelliteIubUsage:0|SchedulingPeriod:100|TQMId:0|TQMId2:0|TQMId3:0|TQMId4:0|ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0|WBTSChangeOrigin:2|WBTSName:ET_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|WBTSSWBuildId:No information available|WinACRABsetupDL:5|WinACRABsetupUL:5|WinLCHSDPA:5|WinLCHSUPA:5|
WBTS|version:xxxxxxx|DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxxx|Id:2770911|name:EU_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0|BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2|BTSSupportForHSPACM:2|BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0|BroadcastSIB15:0|BroadcastSIB15_2:0|BroadcastSIB15_3:0|DCNLinkStatus:0|DCNSecurityStatus:255|DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0|DSCPHigh:46|DSCPLow:0|DSCPMedDCH:34|DSCPMedHSPA:26|DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3|DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1|DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5|DelayThresholdMax:10000|DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000|DelayThresholdMid:7000|DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000|DelayThresholdMin:5000|DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000|EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0|FreqChangeCapability:2|HARQRVConfiguration:1|HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1|HSDPACCEnabled:1|HSDPAULCToDSCP:34|HSUPACCEnabled:1|HSUPADLCToDSCP:34|HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60|IPBasedRouteIdIub:341|IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0|IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0|IPNBId:1117|InactCACThresholdATM:170|InactCACThresholdIP:80|InactUsersCIDThreshold:6|IntelligentSDPrioHO:0|IubTransportSharing:0|LoadControlPeriodPS:20|MDCBufferingTime:50|MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460|MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428|MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0|MeasFiltCoeff:5|MinUDPPortIub:1026|NEType:24|NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0|OverbookingSwitch:0|PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2|PSAveragingWindowSize:4|PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0|PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0|PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0|PWSMInUse:0|PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22|PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0|PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6|PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0|PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22|PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0|PWSMShutdownEndHour:6|PWSMShutdownEndMin:0|PWSMWeekday:0|ProbabilityFactorMax:1000|ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000|PrxAlpha:0|PrxMeasAveWindow:20|PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5|PtxAlpha:0|PtxDPCHmax:-30|PtxDPCHmin:-28|PtxMeasAveWindow:10|RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1|RFSharingState:0|RRIndPeriod:40|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95|RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50|RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1|SBTSId:xxxxx|SatelliteIubUsage:0|SchedulingPeriod:100|TQMId:0|TQMId2:0|TQMId3:0|TQMId4:0|ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0|ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0|WBTSChangeOrigin:2|WBTSName:EU_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx|WBTSSWBuildId:No information available|WinACRABsetupDL:5|WinACRABsetupUL:5|WinLCHSDPA:5|WinLCHSUPA:5|

RA.txt:
RA|version:xxxxx|DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-404490/RA-xxxxxxx|Id:2633805|routingAreaIdLac:xxxxx|routingAreaIdMcc:xxx|routingAreaIdMnc:xx|routingAreaIdRac:x|
RA|version:xxxxx|DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-404500/RA-xxxxxxx|Id:3015559|routingAreaIdLac:xxxxx|routingAreaIdMcc:xxx|routingAreaIdMnc:xx|routingAreaIdRac:x|
```

Sample code for one text file:

```
import sqlite3

tableName = "WBTS"
fileName = "WBTS.txt"
conn = sqlite3.connect("topo.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

#dropQuery = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + tableName
dropQuery = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}' .format(tableName)
cur.execute(dropQuery)
print('table dropped successfully')

#createQuery = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({})' .format(tableName, )
#cur.execute(createQuery)
#print('table created successfully')

with open(fileName, 'r'):
    for line in fileName:
        data = line.split('|')
        createQuery = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({})'.format(tableName, data)
        cur.execute(createQuery)
        print('table created successfully')
        insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES {}'.format(tableName, data)
        cur.execute(insertQuery)
        print('data inserted successfully')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I checked several posts related to sqlite in python but couldn't find the concept to be followed in such case.

Appreciate your support

Comment: what do you expect `data` in `'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({})'.format(tableName, data)` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3, csv

fileName = "WBTS.txt"
with open(fileName, 'r') as wbts:
    for line in csv.reader(wbts, delimiter="|"):
        tableName = line[0]
        data = [ i for i in line if ':' in i]
first_query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({})'.format(tableName, data[0])
# second_query uses list in data[1], third is data[2], and so on

print(data)
```

output:

```
# each line in a list
['version:xxxxxxx', 'DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxx', 'Id:2011659', 'name:VT_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0', 'BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2', 'BTSSupportForHSPACM:2', 'BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0', 'BroadcastSIB15:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_2:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_3:0', 'DCNLinkStatus:0', 'DCNSecurityStatus:255', 'DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'DSCPHigh:46', 'DSCPLow:0', 'DSCPMedDCH:34', 'DSCPMedHSPA:26', 'DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3', 'DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1', 'DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5', 'DelayThresholdMax:10000', 'DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000', 'DelayThresholdMid:7000', 'DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000', 'DelayThresholdMin:5000', 'DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000', 'EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0', 'FreqChangeCapability:2', 'HARQRVConfiguration:1', 'HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1', 'HSDPACCEnabled:1', 'HSDPAULCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPACCEnabled:1', 'HSUPADLCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub:254', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0', 'IPNBId:104', 'InactCACThresholdATM:170', 'InactCACThresholdIP:80', 'InactUsersCIDThreshold:6', 'IntelligentSDPrioHO:0', 'IubTransportSharing:0', 'LoadControlPeriodPS:20', 'MDCBufferingTime:50', 'MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460', 'MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428', 'MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0', 'MeasFiltCoeff:5', 'MinUDPPortIub:1026', 'NEType:24', 'NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0', 'OverbookingSwitch:0', 'PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2', 'PSAveragingWindowSize:4', 'PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0', 'PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0', 'PWSMInUse:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22', 'PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownEndHour:6', 'PWSMShutdownEndMin:0', 'PWSMWeekday:0', 'ProbabilityFactorMax:1000', 'ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000', 'PrxAlpha:0', 'PrxMeasAveWindow:20', 'PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5', 'PtxAlpha:0', 'PtxDPCHmax:-30', 'PtxDPCHmin:-28', 'PtxMeasAveWindow:10', 'RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1', 'RFSharingState:0', 'RRIndPeriod:40', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1', 'SBTSId:xxxxx', 'SatelliteIubUsage:0', 'SchedulingPeriod:100', 'TQMId:0', 'TQMId2:0', 'TQMId3:0', 'TQMId4:0', 'ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'WBTSChangeOrigin:2', 'WBTSName:VT_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'WBTSSWBuildId:No information available', 'WinACRABsetupDL:5', 'WinACRABsetupUL:5', 'WinLCHSDPA:5', 'WinLCHSUPA:5']
['version:xxxxxxx', 'DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxx', 'Id:2110802', 'name:ET_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0', 'BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2', 'BTSSupportForHSPACM:2', 'BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0', 'BroadcastSIB15:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_2:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_3:0', 'DCNLinkStatus:0', 'DCNSecurityStatus:255', 'DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'DSCPHigh:46', 'DSCPLow:0', 'DSCPMedDCH:34', 'DSCPMedHSPA:26', 'DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3', 'DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1', 'DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5', 'DelayThresholdMax:10000', 'DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000', 'DelayThresholdMid:7000', 'DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000', 'DelayThresholdMin:5000', 'DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000', 'EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0', 'FreqChangeCapability:2', 'HARQRVConfiguration:1', 'HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1', 'HSDPACCEnabled:1', 'HSDPAULCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPACCEnabled:1', 'HSUPADLCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub:272', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0', 'IPNBId:110', 'InactCACThresholdATM:170', 'InactCACThresholdIP:80', 'InactUsersCIDThreshold:6', 'IntelligentSDPrioHO:0', 'IubTransportSharing:0', 'LoadControlPeriodPS:20', 'MDCBufferingTime:50', 'MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460', 'MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428', 'MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0', 'MeasFiltCoeff:5', 'MinUDPPortIub:1026', 'NEType:24', 'NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0', 'OverbookingSwitch:0', 'PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2', 'PSAveragingWindowSize:4', 'PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0', 'PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0', 'PWSMInUse:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22', 'PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownEndHour:6', 'PWSMShutdownEndMin:0', 'PWSMWeekday:0', 'ProbabilityFactorMax:1000', 'ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000', 'PrxAlpha:0', 'PrxMeasAveWindow:20', 'PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5', 'PtxAlpha:0', 'PtxDPCHmax:-30', 'PtxDPCHmin:-28', 'PtxMeasAveWindow:10', 'RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1', 'RFSharingState:0', 'RRIndPeriod:40', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1', 'SBTSId:xxxxx', 'SatelliteIubUsage:0', 'SchedulingPeriod:100', 'TQMId:0', 'TQMId2:0', 'TQMId3:0', 'TQMId4:0', 'ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'WBTSChangeOrigin:2', 'WBTSName:ET_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'WBTSSWBuildId:No information available', 'WinACRABsetupDL:5', 'WinACRABsetupUL:5', 'WinLCHSDPA:5', 'WinLCHSUPA:5']
['version:xxxxxxx', 'DistName:"xxxx-xxxx/xxx-xxx/WBTS-xxxx', 'Id:2770911', 'name:EU_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'BTSIPAddress:0.0.0.0', 'BTSRACHCapaIncCapability:2', 'BTSSupportForHSPACM:2', 'BlindHOIntraBTSQCheck:0', 'BroadcastSIB15:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_2:0', 'BroadcastSIB15_3:0', 'DCNLinkStatus:0', 'DCNSecurityStatus:255', 'DLORLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'DSCPHigh:46', 'DSCPLow:0', 'DSCPMedDCH:34', 'DSCPMedHSPA:26', 'DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata:3', 'DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata:1', 'DedicatedMeasReportPeriod:5', 'DelayThresholdMax:10000', 'DelayThresholdMax2msTTI:10000', 'DelayThresholdMid:7000', 'DelayThresholdMid2msTTI:7000', 'DelayThresholdMin:5000', 'DelayThresholdMin2msTTI:5000', 'EnhOLPCRTWPEnabled:0', 'FreqChangeCapability:2', 'HARQRVConfiguration:1', 'HSDPA14MbpsPerUser:1', 'HSDPACCEnabled:1', 'HSDPAULCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPACCEnabled:1', 'HSUPADLCToDSCP:34', 'HSUPAXUsersEnabled:60', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub:341', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub2:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub3:0', 'IPBasedRouteIdIub4:0', 'IPNBId:1117', 'InactCACThresholdATM:170', 'InactCACThresholdIP:80', 'InactUsersCIDThreshold:6', 'IntelligentSDPrioHO:0', 'IubTransportSharing:0', 'LoadControlPeriodPS:20', 'MDCBufferingTime:50', 'MaxBTSOMFrameSize:1460', 'MaxFPDLFrameSizeIub:1428', 'MaxNumberEDCHLCG:0', 'MeasFiltCoeff:5', 'MinUDPPortIub:1026', 'NEType:24', 'NodeBRABReconfigSupport:0', 'OverbookingSwitch:0', 'PDUSize656WithHSDSCH:2', 'PSAveragingWindowSize:4', 'PSRLAveragingWindowSize:0', 'PWSMAVTrafficVERLogic:0', 'PWSMEnableWakeUpTime:0', 'PWSMInUse:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginHour:22', 'PWSMRemCellSDBeginMin:0', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndHour:6', 'PWSMRemCellSDEndMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownBeginHour:22', 'PWSMShutdownBeginMin:0', 'PWSMShutdownEndHour:6', 'PWSMShutdownEndMin:0', 'PWSMWeekday:0', 'ProbabilityFactorMax:1000', 'ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI:1000', 'PrxAlpha:0', 'PrxMeasAveWindow:20', 'PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod:5', 'PtxAlpha:0', 'PtxDPCHmax:-30', 'PtxDPCHmin:-28', 'PtxMeasAveWindow:10', 'RACHloadIndicationPeriod:1', 'RFSharingState:0', 'RRIndPeriod:40', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData:95', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData:100', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3:50', 'RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB:1', 'SBTSId:xxxxx', 'SatelliteIubUsage:0', 'SchedulingPeriod:100', 'TQMId:0', 'TQMId2:0', 'TQMId3:0', 'TQMId4:0', 'ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP:0', 'ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP:0', 'WBTSChangeOrigin:2', 'WBTSName:EU_AO_U_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx', 'WBTSSWBuildId:No information available', 'WinACRABsetupDL:5', 'WinACRABsetupUL:5', 'WinLCHSDPA:5', 'WinLCHSUPA:5']
```